# Hausdorff or weaklly hausdorff may apply

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose that there is a countable collection of open sets
$$\mathbb{B}\{U_1,U_2,…\}$$

which is a basis for the topology of $X$. Let $A\subset X$ and let $x\in \bar{A}$. Prove that there is a sequence in $A$ which converges to $x$.

If I can prove $X$ is Hausdorff, Then done. But how to prove $X$ is Hausdoff will be a big problem...

Comment: But $X$ need not be Hausdorff.  Let $X = \mathbb{N}$ with a basis $U_n =  \{2n,2n-1\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb Z$ define $$V_n=\bigcap\{U_i:i\le n\text{ and }x\in U_i\}.$$Then $V_n$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, so we can choose $a_n\in A\cap V_n$. I claim that the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n,\dots$ converges to $x$. Let a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ be given. Choose $i$ so that $x\in U_i\subseteq W$. Then, for all $n\ge i$, we have$$a_n\in V_n\subseteq U_i\subseteq W.$$

Comment: what if there is only finitely many $U_i$ that contains $x$?

Comment: Why is that a problem? Where did I assume that there is more than one $U_i$ that contains $x$?

Comment: if there is only one $U_i$, is it possible that the $U_i$ only contain finitely many elements?

Comment: The set $V_1$ might be empty… as might $V_2$...

Comment: So when that happened, does the argument still work?

Comment: Claire: The solution bof wrote is absolutely correct. What you should do is read and understand the definition of a convergent sequence in a topological space. Then read the solution again.

Comment: got it! I found the definition of convergence in topological space.
one say that a sequence x_1,x_2,… of points of the space $X$ converges to the point $x$ of $X$ provided that, corresponding to each neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\leq N$.

Comment: @LeeMosher No, $V_i\ne\emptyset$, because $x\in V_i$. If $x\notin U_1$ then $V_1=\bigcap\emptyset=X$.